# Magento 2 how to add a Javascript addeventlistener to element

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, javascript

I am trying to add an event listener to an element, but no matter what I try, it won't work. Here is what I have so far (this is in the html web templates page):

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        document.getElementById('authnetcim-submit').addEventListener("click", function(){
            alert('Alert Message');
        });
    });
```

Everyone keeps saying that the listener needs to be wrapped in `window.addEventListener('load')`, as you need to wait for the page to load before you can add the listeners, but that still won't work for me either. There are no errors and nothing logs to the console. The Id is correct and it's the only id of that name used on the page.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the domReady! dependency. If you're in Magento 2, you should be using require JS anyways. Here's the best of both worlds.

```
define([
    'domReady!'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    //do your thing here
});
```

OR require instead of define. Depends on how you're calling the functionality.

```
require([
    'domReady!'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    //do your thing here
});
```

Comment: I tried this out, but it still wasn't working. I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null." I added in a .phtml file `require([
        'domReady!'
    ], function () {

            alert('phtml loaded');

            var getElementById = document.getElementById("billing-address-same-as-shipping-authnetcim");

                document.getElementById('authnetcim-submit').addEventListener("click", function(){
                    alert('Alert Message');
                });
            });`

Comment: console.log(window) to see if window is null. If it is you have a different issue

Comment: It's not null, it prints Window object.

Comment: how does the authnetcim-submit element get output to the page?

Comment: I believe it's through Knockout.